# The graph fly out of screen when the child number per node is greater than 5

Tags: javascript, layout, cytoscape.js

I learned `cytoscape.js` and related extension some days and tried its many amazing features.

I find that when the number of children is greater than 5 and expand a node, the whole graph fly out of screen.

I constructed more complex data which own 3 parent nodes and 5 child nodes per parent node. There is a connection between any two child nodes.
So there are 3 parent nodes, 15 children nodes and 14+13+12..1 links.

To sum up, when there are more links, the layout behavior looks abnormal.

See my demo below.

You can modify parameters of my function `getInitData()` to see the effect.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

    var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
     container: document.getElementById('cy'),

     ready: function(){
      var api = this.expandCollapse({
       layoutBy: {
        name: "cose-bilkent",
        animate: 'end',
        randomize: false,
        fit: false,
        idealEdgeLength : 150
       },
       fisheye: false,
       animate: true,
       undoable: false
      });
      api.collapseAll();
     },

     style: [
      {
       selector: 'node',
       style: {
        'background-color': '#ad1a66'
       }
      },

      {
       selector: ':parent',
       style: {
        'background-opacity': 0.333
       }
      },

      {
       selector: "node.cy-expand-collapse-collapsed-node",
       style: {
        "background-color": "darkblue",
        "shape": "rectangle"
       }
      },

      {
       selector: 'edge',
       style: {
        'width': 3,
        'line-color': '#ad1a66'
       }
      },

      {
       selector: 'edge.meta',
       style: {
        'width': 2,
        'line-color': 'red'
       }
      },

      {
       selector: ':selected',
       style: {
         "border-width": 3,
        "border-color": '#DAA520'
       }
      }
     ],

     
     elements : getInitData(3, 5)
    });

    var api = cy.expandCollapse('get');
    var elements = null;

    

   });

   function getInitData(parentNum, childrenNum){
    var data = [], children = [], i, j, n;
    for(i = 0; i < parentNum; i++){
     n = "parent"+i;
     data.push({"group":'nodes',data:{"id":n}});
     for(j = 0; j < childrenNum; j++){
      children.push({"group":'nodes',data:{"id":n+"_child_"+j, parent:n}});
     }
    }
    
    var s,t;
    for(i = 0; i < children.length - 1; i++){
     s = children[i].data.id;
     for(j = i+1; j < children.length; j++){
      t = children[j].data.id;
      data.push({"group":'edges',data:{"id":s+"_"+t, source:s, target:t}});
     }
    }
    return data.concat(children);
   }
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica neue, helvetica, liberation sans, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#cy {
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape@3.1.0/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>

<!-- for testing with local version of cytoscape.js -->
<!--<script src="../cytoscape.js/build/cytoscape.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape-cose-bilkent@4.0.0/cytoscape-cose-bilkent.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape-expand-collapse@3.1.1/cytoscape-expand-collapse.js"></script>
<div id="cy"></div>
```

Comment: change the following and see the difference:  `fit: true` in graph init and `position: absolute` in #cy in css

Comment: `fit:true` is effective, while `position: absolute` seems no effect. I find all demos about `"cose-bilkent"` need to set `fit` to `true`. Does it means that `fit:false` maybe has bugs or work unsatisfactory? If set `fit=true` and has only one or nodes on graph, you will get a very big circular node, which looks ugly.

Comment: Fit means fitting the graph to the viewport, if you want to prevent a single node to be too big, set the pading of the graph higher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Solution one:**

Your graph doesn't have any fitting logic. You can implement that yourself with the two methods [`cy.center()`](http://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.center), which centers the graph to the current viewport and [`cy.fit()`](http://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.fit), which zooms the graph to the right position. You would have to call these mehtods everytime you change your graph, e.g. when you add a node, remove a node or, like in your case, expand and collapse. You can do that by binding  these events and calling the said methods there.
Binding, as you know from the last question works like this:

```
cy.unbind('event');
cy.bind('event', 'target', function (event) {...});
```

### **Solution two:**

You can alternatively, if possible (not all layouts can do this), set the method to `fit: true,`, which fits the graph with `cy.fit();` and `cy.center();` internally.

### **Additional problem and solution for that:**

You said, that your graph looks bad when you only have one node in it, so to circumvent that, you can set the padding property of `'cose-bilkent'` to a higher number. You can do that at the initialization in the options.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var padding = 10;
  var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),
    layout: {
      name: 'cose-bilkent',
      animate: false,
      randomize: true
    },
    style: [{
        selector: 'node',
        style: {
          'background-color': '#ad1a66'
        }
      },
      {
        selector: 'edge',
        style: {
          'width': 3,
          'line-color': '#ad1a66'
        }
      }
    ],
    elements: [{
      "data": {
        "id": "glyph9"
      }
    }]
  });
  document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function() {
    padding += 10;
    var layout = cy.layout({
      name: 'cose-bilkent',
      animate: false,
      padding: padding
    });
    layout.run();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
}

button {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>

<html>

<head>
  <title>cytoscape-cose-bilkent.js demo</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape@3.1.0/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>

  <!-- for testing with local version of cytoscape.js -->
  <!--<script src="../cytoscape.js/build/cytoscape.js"></script>-->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape-cose-bilkent@4.0.0/cytoscape-cose-bilkent.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape-expand-collapse@3.1.1/cytoscape-expand-collapse.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <button id="add" type="button">Add padding</button>

  <div id="cy"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think the solution one is a better solution. Solution two fix this issue by `padding`. So I have to modify `padding` dynamically by the number of nodes.
For solution one, I think only center the graph after the first layout , So the following code resolve my issue perfectly.
`cy.on('layoutstop', centerGraph);
function centerGraph(){
    cy.center();
    cy.off('layoutstop', centerGraph);
}`

Comment: Glad i could help